Image doesnt show on screen but is properly loaded using image picker
I have this code here where it supposed when i click the button pick an image from gallery to load phone's gallery and show it in the image component i think image gets loaded properly (I know that because of test logs) it doesnt show up. What's wrong?
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StyleSheet,Platform, Text,Image, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, PanResponder } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

function Homepage() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Request media library permissions when the component mounts
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          Alert.alert(
            'Permission required',
            'Please grant permission to access the photo library to proceed.',
            [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') }]
          );
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
  
    console.log("Image Picker Result:", result);
  
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (

      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button title="Pick an image from gallery" onPress={pickImage} />
        {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} />}
      </View>
  

  );
}

type here

I am expecting when i click the button to open phone's gallery, choose image and show it in the image element above the button
